# Designing an architecture for exchanging data between two systems

Tags: web-services, architecture, data-exchange

I've been tasked with creating an intermediate layer which needs to exchange data (over HTTP) between two independent systems (e.g. Receiver <=> Intermediate Layer (IL) <=> Sender). Receiver and Sender both expose a set of API's via Web Services. Everytime a transaction occurs in the Sender system, the IL should know about it (I'm thinking of creating a Windows Service which constantly pings the Sender), massage the data, then deliver it to the Receiver. The IL can temporarily store the data in a SQL database until it is transferred to the Receiver. I have the following questions -

1. Can WCF (haven't used it a lot) be used to talk to the Sender and Receiver (both expose web services)?
2. How do I ensure guaranteed delivery?
3. How do I ensure security of the messages over the Internet?
4. What are best practices for handling concurrency issues?
5. What are best practices for error handling?
6. How do I ensure reliability of the data (data is not tampered along the way)
7. How do I ensure the receipt of the data back to the Sender?
8. What are the constraints that I need to be aware of?

I need to implement this on MS platform using a custom .NET solution. I was told not to use any middleware like BizTalk. The receiver is an SDFC instance, if that matters.

Any pointers are greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Why not Biztalk (cost or technology issues)?  Would the same restrictions apply to other solutions?  What about Open Source?  Do you *really* have to write all the code yourself?

Comment: Not sure, actually. But I think it could be the cost as it's a small company.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Windows Service that orchestras the exchange sounds fine.
Yes WCF can deal with traditional Web Services.

> How do I ensure guaranteed delivery?

To ensure delivery you can use [TransactionScope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx) to handle the passing of data between the 
`Receiver <=> Intermediate Layer` and `Intermediate Layer <=> Sender` but I wouldn't try and do them together.

You might want to consider some sort of queuing mechanism to send the data to the receiver; I guess I'm thinking more of a logical queue rather than an actual queuing component.  A workflow framework could also be an option.

make sure you have good logging / auditing in place; make sure it's rock solid, has the right information and is easy to read.  Assuming you write a service it will execute without supervision so the operational / support aspects are more demanding.

Think about scenarios:

- How do you manage failed deliveries?
- What happens if the reciever (or sender) is unavailbale for periods of time (and how long is that?); for example: do you need to "escalate" to an operator via email?

> How do I ensure security of the messages over the Internet?

HTTPS. Assuming other existing clients make calls to the Web Services how do they ensure security? (I'm thinking encryption).

> What are best practices for handling concurrency issues?

Hmm probably a separate question.  You should be able to find information on that easily enough.  How much data are we taking? what sort of frequency? How many instances of the Windows Service were you thinking of having - if one is enough why would concurrency be an issue?

> What are best practices for error handling?

Same as for concurrency, but I can offer some pointers:

- Use an established logging framework, I quite like MS EntLibs but there are others (re-using whatever's currently used is probably going to make more sense - if there is anything).
- Remember that execution is unattended so ensure information is complete, clear and unambiguous.  I'd be tempted to log more and dial it down once a level of comfort is reached.
- use a top level handler to ensure nothing get's lost; but don;t be afraid to log deep in the application where you can still get useful context (like the metadata of the data being sent / recieved).

> How do I ensure the receipt of the data back to the Sender?

Include it (sending the receipt) as a step that is part of the transaction.

On a different angle - have a look on CodePlex for ESB type libraries, you might find something useful: http://www.codeplex.com/site/search?query=ESB&ac=8
For example [ESBasic](http://esbasic.codeplex.com/) which seems to be a class library which you could reuse.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed reply! Much appreciated. I'm leaning towards using MSMQ to ensure guaranteed delivery within Transaction Scope. Even if the intermediate system is down, the messages are still in the queue and the system will transmit them once it's back online so I don't lose them. Based on your response, I'm thinking of creating a WCF client which consumes both sender and receiver's webservices, use extensive logging, provide a front-end simple Windows UI so the average user can see what's being pulled in and and sent out, use extensive logging, and use HTTPS. Am I in the right path?

Comment: To answer some of your questions, there could be several thousand transactions per day, not sure about the frequency. I'm thinking of using only one Windows Service but I'm a little concerned about processing the same piece of data twice. Using MSMQ, if the message is in the queue for long, I can send an email to the admin. If the receiver or sender is unavailable, it should be able to pick up from where it left off (how do I accomplish this?). Thank you very much.

Comment: Yeah I think you're on the right path.  I haven't used MSMQ before, my only concern there is how to integrate it with the receiver web services - if you could figure that out it'd be a good solution.

Comment: Oh yeah - as long as you develop it correctly, you can use message queuing via WCF (using MSMQ under the hood).

Comment: No worries - I hope you saw the edit at the bottom regarding checking out Open Source options. :)